Razor page and update model through javascript
In my .NET razor page I have field like this:
<InputTextArea @bind-Value="Data.values" rows="4" />`  

<button type="button" onclick="AddValues()"> Add </button>

Here AddValues is a JavaScript function and click of this hardcoded values gets assigned to the field like some pretext "**----**" and insert the value in the InputTextArea field.
But since model is assigned to the field Data.values it does not get updated when I click on the "Save" button I mean on form post event.
Does anybody have any idea how to update the model of the InputTextArea field when I click on AddValues(), so that when I am submitting the form, it would get latest values of the model and save that to the database?

possible duplicate of Changing an Input value in Blazor by javascript doesn't change it's binded property value.

Doing this through JS is almost certainly wrong.  The Blazor and browser DOM's get out of sync and you get unpredictable results.  You need to provide more code on what AddValues does for anyone to show you how to do what you want in pure c#.

You could try following sample:
@page "/"
<form  @formname="form1" @onsubmit="Submit" >
    <AntiforgeryToken />
        <InputTextArea id="text1" @bind-Value="Data.values" />
        <button type="button" onclick="add()" >Add</button>
        <button type="submit" formmethod="post"  @formname="form1">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function add() {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
        text1.value = "** ----**"+text1.value;
        text1.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
</script>


@code{

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private MyData Data { get; set; } = new MyData();

    private void Submit(){
        var result = Data.values;
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string values { get; set; }
    }
}

